# Images cut off in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm seeing something odd in IE where the background images I expect to see, do not appear.

Here is my CSS:

```
#grey.internal #leader p{color: #525051;}
#grey h1 {color: #bc35b7;}
#grey.internal #for .forcont{ border:none;margin:0;}
#grey #leader p {font-size: 18px; line-height: 32px; width: 760px; margin: 0 auto; }
#grey #leader ul.section-links {padding: 32px 0 62px 0; width: 700px; margin: 155px auto 0 auto;height: 100%; border: 1px red solid; }
#grey #leader ul.section-links li {display: inline-block; margin: 0 6%;}
* html #grey #leader ul.section-links li { /* for IE6 */ display: inline;}
*+html #grey #leader ul.section-links li { /* for IE7 */ display: inline;}
#grey #leader ul.section-links li h2 a {color: #525051; text-decoration: none; height: 100%;  border: 1px blue solid;}
#grey #leader ul.section-links li h2 a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
#grey #leader ul.section-links li h2 a.payments {background: url('/_/img/icon-payments.png') no-repeat 0 0; padding: 135px 30px 0 0; }
#grey #leader ul.section-links li h2 a.identity {background: url('/_/img/icon-identity.png') no-repeat 8px 0; padding: 135px 50px 0 60px; margin-right: 20px;}
#grey #leader ul.section-links li h2 a.analytics {background: url('/_/img/icon-analytics.png') no-repeat 10px 0; padding: 135px 0 0 0;}
```

And here is the html block:

```
<section id="leader">
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <ul class="section-links">
        <li class="p-item"><div class="icont"><h2><a href="/mobile-payments/" class="payments">Payments</a></h2></div></li>
        <li class="i-item"><div class="icont"><h2><a href="/identity/" class="identity">Identity</a></h2></div></li>
        <li class="a-item"><div class="icont"><h2><a href="/mobile-analytics/" class="analytics">Analytics</a></h2></div></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

And this is what I see in IE(6-8):
[image: IE screenshot]

And this is what I see in Chrome:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

I've added the borders just to give me a clue as to what's going on!

Comment: I assume you are referring to background: url('/_/img/icon-payments.png'), background: url('/_/img/icon-identity.png') and {background: url('/_/img/icon-analytics.png')
Can you browse to these images in your browser? IE is the file path correct in your solution?

Comment: Hi, yes I can browse to them.

Comment: Can you make a demo that shows the problem? http://jsbin.com/ / http://jsfiddle.net/, the images aren't important but you could use http://placekitten.com/ or something.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has to do with `<section>` tag. As it's HTML5, which IE <9 doesn't support, the section tag will not contain anything (and becoming automatically closed, thus rendering all of your css useless). Either change it to something else, or include https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/